# throw Exceptions FirebaseAuth not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating a `FirebaseDAO` that executes and deals with the main issues of Firebase and how I need to handle the problems and show to the user I am trying to pass Exceptions using throw but even when I try to register a user with a short password or email I repeat he is not launching Exception.
Where is my error, can anyone help me?

```
public class FirebaseDAO {
    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;        
    private Task<AuthResult> authResultTask = null;

    public void cadastrarUsuarioAuth(final Usuario usuario) throws FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException, FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException {

        mFirebaseAuth = ConfigurationFirebase.getFirebaseAuth();
        try{
            authResultTask = mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(usuario.getEmail(), usuario.getSenha());

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();

            if(!authResultTask.isSuccessful() || !authResultTask.isComplete()){

                if (authResultTask.getException()!=null){
                    String tException =  authResultTask.getException().getClass().toString();
                    if(tException.equalsIgnoreCase(FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException.class.toString())){
                        FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException eWeakPassword = (FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException)authResultTask.getException();

                        throw eWeakPassword;
                    }
                    if(tException.equalsIgnoreCase(FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException.class.toString())){
                        FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException eCollision = (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException)authResultTask.getException();

                        throw eCollision;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will not work the way you expect at all.

First, `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is asynchronous, meaning it returns immediately with a Task object.  You have to add listeners to that task to find out the results.  You can't just reach into it to figure out what happened.

Second, inside the listener that you attach to the task, you won't be able to throw an exception that will get caught in the enclosing method.  The enclosing method is going to return immediately without waitint for `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` to complete.

You'll have to adapt your code to an asynchronous style of programming.  You can read more about that [in this article](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93).

Comment: But because all the exeplos I see when someone accesses a function of the Direct Firebase in an Activity or Freagment does not do that, they just call it the same as I did.

Ok, the projects I see use addOnCompleteListener but I think that's not what you're talking about !!!

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm talking about.  You need to attach listeners to that Task to get the result.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I'm going to have to use an MVP with several Interfaces !!!

```
public class FirebaseDAO {

    private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference;
    private Task<AuthResult> authResultTask = null;

    private Presenter mPresenter;

    public void cadastrarUsuarioAuth(final Usuario usuario) {

        mFirebaseAuth = ConfigurationFirebase.getFirebaseAuth();

            authResultTask = mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(usuario.getEmail(), usuario.getSenha());

            authResultTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    if(e.getClass().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(FirebaseAuthWeakPasswordException.class.toString())){
                        presenter.BlaBlaBla(R.string.error_weak_password); //At present I invoke to call a view.showDialog
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```